# Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 'log' while trying to build and run a docker image

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to build and run a docker container. after step 11/11 I get.

```
Step 11/11 : USER node
 ---> Running in 4c8f2eb2f8c1
Removing intermediate container 4c8f2eb2f8c1
 ---> 93981068fb83
Successfully built 93981068fb83
Successfully tagged flashbot:latest

"/app/node_modules/streamroller/lib/RollingFileWriteStream.js:282
          throw e;
          ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 'log'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1336:3)
    at mkdir (/app/node_modules/streamroller/lib/RollingFileWriteStream.js:270:19)
    at RollingFileStream._renewWriteStream (/app/node_modules/streamroller/lib/RollingFileWriteStream.js:299:5)
    at new RollingFileWriteStream (/app/node_modules/streamroller/lib/RollingFileWriteStream.js:94:10)
    at new RollingFileStream (/app/node_modules/streamroller/lib/RollingFileStream.js:18:5)
    at openTheStream (/app/node_modules/log4js/lib/appenders/file.js:64:20)
    at fileAppender (/app/node_modules/log4js/lib/appenders/file.js:84:16)
    at Object.configure (/app/node_modules/log4js/lib/appenders/file.js:144:10)
    at /app/node_modules/log4js/lib/appenders/index.js:117:29
    at Object.onlyOnMaster (/app/node_modules/log4js/lib/clustering.js:87:50) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: 'log'
}"
```

here is my Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM node:16.14

WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

COPY package.json .
RUN yarn set version berry

COPY .yarn tsconfig.json .yarnrc.yml ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . ./
RUN yarn build

CMD [ "node", "dist/index.js" ]
USER node
```

I have tried a few solutions I found after doing some googling with no success. Decided to make a post after spending a lot of time with this error. Is it a permisson issue with node? I have the same issue on both mac and ubuntu.

Comment: Are you getting this issue when you're building the container, or when you're running it?  (The logs sort of look like the build runs to completion and then the error message is running the container.)  Can you configure your application to log to stdout rather than a file?

Comment: When running it. It finishes building then immediately errors out. I am going to look into that now. I'm not sure how to do that, but I appreciate the input thanks.